# optimizing SQL query with agregate index

Tags: mysql

I'm looking for the best query possible to get the newest date of a given record set where the fields I need to filter are:

- CreateDate : DATETIME
- TransactionStatus : VARCHAR(10)
- DocumentSeries : VARCHAR(45)

The simpler query is this one

```
SELECT MAX(CreateDate) FROM transactionsheaders WHERE TransactionStatus="N" AND DocumentSeries='Z';
```

When I use explain I get

```
EXPLAIN(SELECT MAX(CreateDate) FROM transactionsheaders WHERE TransactionStatus="N" AND DocumentSeries='Z');
+----+-------------+---------------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table               | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+---------------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | transactionsheaders | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 5752 | Using where |
+----+-------------+---------------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
```

for a total record set of 5715.

Ok, I have no indexes to use and I'm using text and datetime columns... I guess this isn't an easy scenario so I decided to add a column to the table that has the same meaning as DocumentSeries but is an int, so the query will be:

```
SELECT MAX(CreateDate) FROM transactionsheaders WHERE TransactionStatus="N" AND DocumentSeriesUID=2;
```

and added an index which agregates the 3 columns with

```
ALTER TABLE `transactionsheaders` ADD INDEX `index_doc_series` (`DocumentSeriesUID` ASC, `CreateDate` ASC, `TransactionStatus` ASC);
```

and explain outputs

```
+----+-------------+---------------------+------+------------------+------------------+---------+-------+------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table               | type | possible_keys    | key              | key_len | ref   | rows | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+---------------------+------+------------------+------------------+---------+-------+------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | transactionsheaders | ref  | index_doc_series | index_doc_series | 4       | const | 2876 | Using where; Using index |
+----+-------------+---------------------+------+------------------+------------------+---------+-------+------+--------------------------+
```

**Q1.** Well... apparently I'm using less data, but if I do a count with the same conditions, I get 5703 results, so, this is a little confusing. I know that EXPLAIN estimates the number of rows the query needs to fetch, but how can it be s off?

Then again, I don't need to get everything all at once, so my next test would be to fetch the top 10 results that fit my search criteria

```
SELECT MAX(Q.CreateDate) FROM((SELECT CreateDate FROM transactionsheaders WHERE TransactionStatus="N" AND DocumentSeriesUID='2' ORDER BY CreateDate DESC LIMIT 10) as Q);
```

but... If I'm using ORDER BY, I don't need MAX and I just limit to 1?

```
SELECT CreateDate FROM transactionsheaders WHERE TransactionStatus="N" AND DocumentSeriesUID='2' ORDER BY CreateDate DESC LIMIT 1;
```

and EXPLAIN yields the same result as the query using MAX.

Well, all of this is just to ask how can I optimize this query? Is it already optimized by sung the index? Can I go further?

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the query

```
SELECT MAX(CreateDate)
FROM transactionsheaders
WHERE TransactionStatus="N" AND DocumentSeriesUID=2;
```

the index should be `(TransactionStatus, DocumentSeriesUID, CreateDate)` or `(DocumentSeriesUID, TransactionStatus, CreateDate)` depending on the cardinality. You first use the conditions on the fields and then look for the maximum CreateDate within the found rows.

Answer (score 0):

When you define a multi-field index, you have to ensure you use the fields in the order they're specified.

e.g. given an `index(a,b,c)`, then

```
... where a=?
... where a=? and b=?    
... where b=? and a=?
... where a=? and b=? and c=?
```

can all use the index, as you've used the fields of the index in the order they're defined. In your case, you've done

```
... where a=? and c=?
```

and omitted b, which prevents use of that index. Think of the fields in a multi-field index as "chained". To able to reach the 'c' fields in the index, you have to pass through 'b', but you've not specified any 'b' fields in your where clauses.

Note that if you have `a,b,c` for index fields, then your where clause just has to use all of them, the actual order the fields appear in the where clause is irrelevant - it's the presence/absence of the fields that counts.

Either re-arrange your index definition, so that it goes `a,c,b`, or create a secondary index that has just `a,c` for fields.